# I am getting the error in 48th line as "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getElement'' "

Tags: javascript

I am getting the error in  line as

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method  'getElement'

so please refer my code in javascript file

```
addnavbtn: function(){

    if (!(Browser.ie && Browser.version < 9)) {
        var jlevel0 = this.menu.getElement('ul.level0');

        if(jlevel0){
            var jmega = this.menu;

            var jbutton = new Element ('div', {id:'js-megamenu-button', 'class': 'js-megamenu-button', html: 'Navigation', styles: { display: 'none'}}).inject (jmega, 'before');

            jbutton.addEvent('click', function(e){
                e.stop();

                if(jmega.getStyle('display') == 'block'){
                    jmega.removeClass('active').setStyle('display', 'none');
                    jbutton.removeClass('active');
                } else {
                    jmega.addClass('active').setStyle('display', 'block');
                    jbutton.addClass('active');
                }
            });
```

Comment: What the exception says. `this.menu` doesn't have the method `getElement`. Did you give it a `getElement` method?

Comment: Why don't you console.log the `this.menu` on the line above where you call `.getElement`, and see what it says is in it? Using something like the Chrome dev tools, you can do all kinds of fun stuff, and inspect all of the properties of your object.

Comment: yes its showing in google chrome console as “Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getElement'

Comment: ...so on the line ***before*** `this.menu.getElement(...);`, write `console.log(this.menu);` and it will give you an item that you can open, and check out. And you can see if `.getElement` is available, and if not, why...  You can also make sure that you're not calling `addnavbutton` as a callback, or in an event-listener, or as a parameter to a function...  ...because if you do any of these things (all pretty much the same), then `this` will point to `window`, and not your intended object.

Answer (score 0):

this.menu should be coming 'undefined' in your case. Do an alert on 'this.menu'

Answer (score 0):

...so on the line ***before*** `this.menu.getElement(...);`, write `console.log(this.menu);` and it will give you an item that you can open, and check out. And you can see if `.getElement` is available, and if not, why...

You can also make sure that you're not calling `addnavbutton` as a callback, or in an event-listener, or as a parameter to a function...  ...because if you do any of these things (all pretty much the same), then `this` will point to `window`, and not your intended object.